# Accessing Class variables from another class

Tags: python, class, subclassing, class-instance-variables

How do you access an instance in an object and pass it to another 'main' object? I'm working with a parser for a file that parses different tags, INDI(individual), BIRT(event), FAMS(spouse), FAMC(children)

Basically there are three classes: Person, Event, Family

```
class Person():
    def __init__(self, ref):
        self._id = ref
        self._birth : None

    def addBirth(self, event):
        self._birth: event

class Event():
    def __init__(self, ref):
        self._id = ref
        self._event = None

    def addEvent(self, event):
        self._event = event

        #**event = ['12 Jul 1997', 'Seattle, WA'] (this is generated from a     function outside a class)
```

I want to transfer self._event from the Event class into addBirth method to add it into my person class. I have little knowledge on how classes and class inhertiances work. Please help!

Comment: Just add an argument to the desired methods and pass it from an appropriate caller?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want to pass an (for example) `Event` object to an instance of `Person`?

Honestly, I don't understand the intent of your code, but you probably just need to pass `self` from one class instance to the other class instance.

`self` references the current instance.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self):
        self._events = []

    def add_event(self, event)
        self._events.append(event)

class Event:
    def add_to_person(self, person):
        person.add_event(self)
```

Answer (score 0):

The most proper way to handle situations like this is to use `getter` and `setter` methods; data encapsulation is important in OO programming. I don't always see this done in Python where I think it should, as compared to other languages. It simply means to add methods to your classes who sole purpose are to return args to a caller, or modify args from a caller. For example

Say you have class `A` and `B`, and class `B` (caller) wants to use a variable `x` from class `A`. Then class `A` should provide a `getter` interface to handle such situations. Setting you work the same:

```
class class_A():
    def __init__(self, init_args):
        x = 0

    def someMethod():
        doStuff()

    def getX():
        return x

    def setX(val):
        x = val

class class_B():
    def init(self):
        init_args = stuff
        A = class_A(init_args)
        x = class_A.getX()

    def someOtherMethod():
        doStuff()
```

So if class `B` wanted the `x` property of an instance object `A` of class `class_A`, `B` just needs to call the `getter` method.

As far as passing instances of objects themselves, say if you wanted `A` to pass an already-created instance object of itself to a method in class `B`, then indeed, you simply would pass `self`.